# For Nodejs http module, what is the difference between 'http.get' and 'http.request'?

Tags: node.js

I read the nodejs document,it says that the only difference between these two function is that http.get will execute req.end automatically.But I got a weird question.I write some codes like these:

```
    http.get(url,function(res){
      var data="";
          res.on('data',function(chunk){
             data+=chunk;
           });
          res.on('end',function(){
              console.log(data);
           });
     }).on("error",function(){
      });
```

in this place,the data works fine.But when I use http.request,something is wrong.

```
   var pReq = http.request(options, function(pRes) {
        var data=" ";
        pRes.on('data',function (chunk) {
            data+=chunk;
        });
        pRes.on('end',function() {
            console.log(data)
        });
      }).on('error', function(e) { 
   });
```

in this place,I always got Garbled.I'm new in node,are there any mistakes about the sencode one?

Comment: "Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node.js provides this convenience method. The only difference between this method [`http.get()`] and `http.request()` is that it sets the method to GET and calls `req.end()` automatically." – https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback